# Chrome has lost its console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I open up chrome (fresh from re-installing it) and press F12 to get the dev tools the following code returns and error:

```
console.debug('test');
```

The error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: console is not defined(…)`

This happens regardless of the site I am on.

`console` should not be a generic object.

**Any ideas how I can get console back?**

UPDATE: I have tried uninstalling and re-installing chrome. That did not work.  I installed the canary version of chrome (which makes a separate profile) and that version did work.

I got some advice while troubleshooting a problem in my web app.  That advice told me to run `delete window.console`\ `delete console`.

I worry that this has messed me up.

Comment: are you able to still do stuff like `document.querySelectorAll` and stuff normally?

Comment: Now I'm tempted to run that delete thing but I'm worried it'll mess me up too :P  This makes me wonder, though, what if a site ran that?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling with "Also Delete my Browsing data" as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en) and restarting? Looks like chrome has left behind some data.

Comment: The `delete` may prevent console from working, but it should come back - if not when you load a different page, then surely when you restart Chrome.

Comment: @Firedrake969 I just tried it, and am not getting any persistent errors. Maybe there's a browser extension at play?

Comment: Interesting note if I press ctrl + shift + j on this window it opens a debug console that will not have window.console defined. But if in the debug window I press ctrl + shift + j again (debugging the debug window), then that console works....

Comment: @sircapsalot yes that works fine

Comment: @Nivas I will give that a try

Comment: wow that's weird @Vaccano..

Comment: @Nivas - that did it.  Post as answer and I will accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling with "Also delete my browsing data" as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en) and restarting the computer.

Looks like Chrome has left behind some data.